# Datatable's interface is not working properly

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]

I just added a datatable without configuration and this is the result i have.. I don't know why this happend. I have already tried to overwrite the css with `style="width100%"`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#department').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
                <h4>Department</h4>
                <table class="table table-hover" id="department" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>asd</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            foreach($department as $key => $value){
                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td>'.$value->id.'</td>
                                    <td>'.Department.'</td>
                                </tr>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Without a [mre], it's difficult to provide help. My guess is: You have CSS somewhere on the page which is interfering with the default layout.

Comment: Your snippet contains PHP code. Please, remove it with a real plain HTML example.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed code snippet in the question shows a correct output. The only difference is it includes the dependencies assets, both jQuery and DataTables. Also, DataTables has a CSS default asset, which has been included in the fixed snippet. Probably you missed this in your source code:

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```